# Launch to specific screen of OutSystem mobile app from native iOS and Android app

Tags: android, ios, outsystems

I'm new to Outsystems and we are stuck with a scenario where we want to launch a specific screen of Outsystems mobile application from our native iOS and Android app.

We have already added URL Schemes to Outsystems mobile app using corodova plugin. Also added `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` to my native iOS app. Android app is still in development.

Outsystems app is launching from native iOS app, but we need launch it to a specific screen. We have a login page in Outsystems app, we need to bypass that.

I assumed the outsystems app must be working on URLs or deeplinking, but looks like its not the case.

Can you guys help me out here?? Even a vague idea to achieve it will be helpful.

**For Android developers who need native code (Kotlin) to launch Outsystems app**

```
val packageName = "in.co.companyname.appname"
            val context = getActivity()
            val pm = context!!.packageManager

            val myAction = Uri.parse("in.co.companyname.appname://Module/Screen?parameter1=para1&parameter2=para2")
            // Initialize a new Intent
            val intent: Intent? = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
            if(intent!=null){
                intent!!.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                intent!!.setData(myAction)
                context!!.startActivity(intent)
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(activity!!, "Please install the App", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
```

**For iOS developers**

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL.init(string: "in.co.companyname.appname://Module/Screen?parameter1=para1&parameter2=para2")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This documentation](https://success.outsystems.com/Documentation/Development_FAQs/How_to_Define_Mobile_App_Deep_Links) should help...I have tested with Android, and was able to successfully construct deep links and encode them in an NFC tag.

Short version: the deep link is constructed with the following syntax:

```
<app-identifier>://<module>/<screen>
```

where app-identifier is the native app identifier for your app, and module and screen are the module and screen name you want to open with the deep link.

As I do not have an iOS device handy, I was not able to test on iOS specifically.

Comment: Just to give my 2 cents here: it would be helpful if the syntax would include parameters (when applicable). I would also point out this excerpt from the question: "We have a login page in Outsystems app, we need to bypass that." This means that the destination page should be marked as anonymous-accessible, otherwise the login page will always be shown.